# Python Web Scraping - Dynamic Loading Page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using the python scrapy framework (accepting sugestions of other libs) for scraping a flight tickets website, but when requesting the page it doesn't return the whole thing.

The page has some POST requests that has as response the prices, but this query takes few seconds, so I don't get the full HTML.

Page before query:

```
<div id="prices">
</div>
```

Page after query:

```
<div id="prices">
    <div id="price">
        Flight price with info
    </div>
    <div id="price">
        Flight price with info
    </div>
    <div id="price">
        Flight price with info
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure I can fake the POST request and get the json response since there is some API endpoint protection.

How could I get the page after the query, when fully loaded?

Comment: Can you post a link to the page you want to scrape ?

Comment: If it's dynamically loaded with JavaScript you might need to use selenium

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ sure but is in portuguese, here is the url that goes for a search Sao Paulo -> Montreal: https://www.viajanet.com.br/busca/voos-resultados#/SAO/YMQ/RT/23-12-2018/03-01-2019/-/-/-/1/0/0/-/-/BRL/-

Comment: https://www.viajanet.com.br/passagens-aereas/quandoviajar/api/cityPair/chart/SAO/YMQ/

Comment: You need to use Selenium or something like Splash to scrape it, because the prices are dynamically loaded using javascript.